# application dying at port creation

Tags: java, android, sockets, port

My application crashes when trying to open a connection in the following code. I believe it is because the port is being used, but im not sure. Let me know if you see anything wrong with the code below or have any idea what the problem may be. The application makes it to

> Log.v("connectdevice", "after
>   ipadress");

SOME times it will make it past that point. But is rarely. Also, there is no exception caught.

Thanks in advance!

```
    try {
        Log.v("connectdevice", "inside make connection");
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.201.65");
        Log.v("connectdevice", "after ipadress");
        socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7777);
        Log.v("connectdevice", "after socket");
        connected = true;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            connected = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connected = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: There is no exception? Not even in logcat? What makes your program crash then?

Comment: logcat does not show anything except the outputs from the Log.v. Any ideas? Am i handling all the possible exceptions?

Comment: That is strange. I only see that  new Socket(host.getHostName(), 7777) is a little sub-optimal, as this might (?) include a reverse DNS lookup. Socket will accept InetAddress. Just use Socket(host, 7777).

Comment: Trying now. Will let you know result

Comment: Working like a charm now. That is weird. Thanks, if you post this fix as an answer, i will give you some rep and accept the answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Posted by ssfn]
>   That is strange. I only see that new
>   Socket(host.getHostName(), 7777) is a
>   little sub-optimal, as this might (?)
>   include a reverse DNS lookup. Socket
>   will accept InetAddress. Just use
>   Socket(host, 7777).

If ssfn comes by and puts his answer here, i am going to accept it asap. Until then, this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Log.e("Error", "exception", e);
```

This way you can see the Exceptions on Logcat

Comment: Shouldn't my "catches" already be printing the exceptions that are caught to logcat. So, what exactly is your suggestion doing for me?

Comment: Uncaught exceptions should show up in logcat. Besides that, e.printStackTrace() will print to stdout/stderr, which should also be redirected to logcat.